# Go channel not deadlocked or locked

Tags: go

I have a small snippet of code like this

```
func main() {
    var c chan string
    go func() {
        c <- "let's get started"//write1
        //c <- "let's get started"//write2
        //c <- "let's get started"//write3
        fmt.Println("wrote the stuff....")
    }()
    //time.Sleep(3 * time.Second) //adding this always shows fatal exception
    c = make(chan string)
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}
```

I do not see the output `wrote the stuff....` on console if I uncomment `//write2` and `write3` code snippet lines. I understand that probably I don't see it is because the channel is unbuffered and totally synchronous, and there is only one read happening outside the channel. However, when program exits, the go routine is blocked, why is there no error like `deadlocked...` or something in this case that I see?

Answer (score 6):

Create the channel *before* you try to write to it. If the `func` goroutine tries to send elements through `c` before there's actually a channel there, it ends up using a nil channel, which blocks forever.

Comment: That was an observation that I deliberately did. Q is , since channel blocks and later I initialize it, should it not just unblock and work? I am not able to understand the problem it can cause.

Comment: @curiousengineer: No. It's not going to monitor the `c` variable and switch channels when `c` gets assigned. It's trying to send on a nil channel, and it's going to stay on that channel. The channel and the variable are separate.

Comment: thanks, that is helpful, hence, when I add a 2-3 second sleep right before the ``incorrect location of make...``, I do see the fatal exception. I guess right now program is apparently working because the channel is mostly getting initialized, and adding a sleep makes the situation deliberate? I changed the snippet so that you can see what I mean. Is my understanding correct now?

Comment: However, now if I move the ``make`` to correct location, and write to channel once and read once, things are perfect, but if I write 3 times and read only once, why is the deadlock not coming now?

Comment: If you write 3 times and read only once you have a goroutine leak but not a deadlock as the main routine will exit after reading the first value.

Comment: @ain, thanks. After I have written once, I do one read, the 2nd write will go into the channel and no one will read it. That is what I understand. The third write is where the go routine is blocked is what I understand. I understand mem leaks and all quite well from C days, here can you explain if the channel is blocked, why is it not a dead lock and the leak is the resources being leaked with this blocked go routine?

Comment: No, because the channel is unbuffered, the goroutine which writes into the channel will block on the secod write. So the goroutine will be sitting there, waiting someone to read from the channel, so it can write (the second value) into it. But in the meantime the main routine exits and thus program finishes. At that time the goroutine is still running, althought it is in blocked state. This means the goroutine is leaked, but there is no deadlock.

Comment: @ain, after the main routine exits are you saying system level resource is leaked forever? Usually when a program is killed mem is returned to system mostly. Here the routine is leaking resource even if main program exited? Is there some good literature explaining these in detail?

Comment: When main exits then OS will release all resources of the proccess, so no "resource is leaked forever". It is just that well written program should terminate it's goroutines itself, not leave them running.

Comment: @ain, u have been helpful thanks. I understand well things like if two threads each take a lock and then want to wait on a lock that the other has it is deadlock. Or a wrong thread wakes up cannot take a lock and sleeps all might lock. What would be a dead lock scenario for channels and generally programming language might not know of it but goland does throw that panic at times. Can you tell me what deadlock means in channel world

Answer (score -2):

This is an interesting experiment. I don't know if its possible but this type of error should be caught by the compiler, there should be a feature that checks at the compile-time if anything is writing in a `nil` channel.